# how do i get message list with Gmail Api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-docs-api, gmail-api

i want to access list of messages

Object:

```
2.0.0-p481 :008 > g.gmail_api.users.messages.list
=> # < Google::APIClient::Method:0x41c948c ID:gmail.users.messages.list >
```

i'm new in this API and unable to get how do i use Gmail API.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Google
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem "google-api-client"
```

in my model

```
def query_google( email )
    self.refresh_token_from_google if self.expires_at.to_i < Time.now.to_i

    @google_api_client = Google::APIClient.new(
      application_name: 'Joggle',
      application_version: '1.0.0'
    )

    @google_api_client.authorization.access_token = self.access_key
    @gmail = @google_api_client.discovered_api('gmail', "v1")


    # https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list
    # Now that we instantiated gmail, we can take the category (messages) and the method
    # You can also add parameters if you wish to do so:
    # @calendar_events = google_api_client.execute(
    #     :api_method => @calendar.events.list,
    #     :parameters => {
    #         "calendarId" => current_user.email,
    #         'timeMin' => date.to_s,
    #         'timeMax' => max_date.to_s
    #         # 'items' => [{'id' => current_user.email}]
    #     },
    #     :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
    # )
    @emails = @google_api_client.execute(
        api_method: @gmail.users.messages.list,
        parameters: {
            userId: "me",

            # searching messages based on number of queries:
            # https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering
            q: "from:" + email.to_s
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
    )


    count = @emails.data.messages.count
    Rails.logger.error count 
    {count: count, last_emails: get_three_emails} if count > 0



end
```

for reference : https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/135

Answer (score 0):

Not a ruby expert but that looks like a method, can you call () it?  I imagine you've gone through steps to setup authentication, etc?  the messages.list() function should be able to be called without any parameters generally (well, you may need to specify a userId, which you can just use "me" for to get the authenticated user).

Comment: i already done authentication via OmniAuth. i have token and refresh token. i don't know how to use it. any JavaScript startup example can help.